# How to use normalization to set levels of confidence between a rating and the number of ratings in Python or SQL?

Tags: sql, normalization

I have a list of about 800 sales items that have a rating (from 1 to 5), and the number of ratings. I'd like to list the items that are most probable of having a "good" rating in an unbiased way, meaning that 1 person voting 5.0 isn't nearly as good as 50 people having voted and the rating of the item being a 4.5.

Initially I thought about getting the smallest amount of votes (which will be zero 99% of the time), and the highest amount of votes for an item on the list and factor that into the ratings, giving me a confidence level of 0 to 100%, however I'm thinking that this approach would be too simplistic.

I've heard about Bayesian probability but I have no idea on how to implement it. My list of items, ratings and number of ratings is on a MySQL view, but I'm parsing the code using Python, so I can make the calculations on either side (but preferably at the SQL view).

Is there any practical way that I can normalize this voting with SQL, considering the rating and number of votes as parameters?

```
|----------|--------|--------------|
| itemCode | rating | numOfRatings |
|----------|--------|--------------|
| 12330    | 5.00   | 2            |
| 85763    | 4.65   | 36           |
| 85333    | 3.11   | 9            |
|----------|--------|--------------|
```

I've started off trying to assign percentiles to the rating and numOfRatings, this way I'd be able to do normalization (sum them with an initial 50/50 weight). Here's the code I've attempted:

```
SELECT p.itemCode AS itemCode, (p.rating - min(p.rating)) / (max(p.rating) - min(p.rating)) AS percentil_rating,
(p.numOfRatings - min(p.numOfRatings)) / (max(p.numOfRatings) - min(p.numOfRatings)) AS percentil_qtd_ratings
FROM products p
WHERE p.available = 1
GROUP BY p.itemCode
```

However that's only bringing me a result for the first itemCode on the list, not all of them.

Comment: What's the current code you have, if any?

Comment: @abdullahalali added some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly the issue here is the low number of observations your data has. Implementing Bayesian's method is the way to go because it provides great probability distribution for applications involving ratings especially if there is limited observations, and it easily decides the future likelihood ratio based on given parameters (this [article](https://www.psychologicalscience.org/observer/bayes-for-beginners-probability-and-likelihood) provides an excellent explanation about Bayesian probability for beginners).

I would suggest storing your data in CSV files so it becomes easier to manipulate in python. Denormalizing the data via joins is the first task to do before analyzing your ratings.

This is Bayesian's simplified formula to use in your python code:

[image: formula]

```
R – Confidence level aka number of observations
v – number of votes for a single product
C – avg vote for all products
m - tuneable parameter aka cutoff number required for votes to be considered (How many votes do you want displayed)
```

Since this is the simplified formula, this [article](https://fulmicoton.com/posts/bayesian_rating/) explains how its been derived from its original formula. This [article](https://www.fxsolver.com/browse/formulas/Bayes+estimator+-+Internet+Movie+Database+%28IMDB%29) is helpful too in explaining the parameters.

Knowing the formula pretty much gets 50% of your work done, the rest is just importing your data and working with it. I provided below examples similar to your problem in case you need full demonstration:

[Github example 1](https://github.com/DistrictDataLabs/blog-files/blob/master/computing-bayesian-average-of-star-ratings/code/bayes.py)

[Github example 2](https://github.com/wbotelhos/rating)

Comment: Thanks, the github examples (especially the 2nd one) were really helpful!